# Android - Reading and writing from file

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android programming.
I am trying to provide a form to user for inputting some information. 
I want to write that information in a file and then read it from file and show it in a `TextView`. Currently, what I read is `null`. Can you please help me with this issue?
The code is this one:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append("Event name: " + editText1.getText() + "|");
        s.append("Date: " + editText2.getText() +  "|");
        s.append("Details: " + editText3.getText() + "|");

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file= new File(extStorageDirectory, "config.txt");
        try {
            writeToFile(s.toString().getBytes(), file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // read from file and show in text view
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String filename = "config.txt";
        String str = readFromFile(context, filename);
        String first = "You have inputted: \n";
        first += str;
        textView.setText(first);

    }
});
```

Write function:

```
public static void writeToFile(byte[] data, File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(data);
    }
    finally {
        if (bos != null) {
            try {
                bos.flush ();
                bos.close ();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read function:

```
public String readFromFile(Context context, String filename) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return "";
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right file path?

Comment: I would have an error if I didn't. But I have no errors nor warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getText()` method of Edittext returns `editable` . So first you should convert it into string by using toString() function . And also check whether you have given WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission .

Answer (score 0):

If I am not missing something you write to file

```
String extStorageDirectory = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file= new File(extStorageDirectory, "config.txt");
```

But you read from

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
```

The latter one uses a dir inside the application base directory, whereas the output goes to the base dir of the external strage directory.

Why not use `context.openFileOutput()` instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

If the file should be stored externally, try as follows: The way you create your `File` object remains the same. Instead of `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);` (for writing) please use `FileInputStream`. Please remeber to set appropriate permissions in the manifest. Under which conditions they are neccessary please consult the Android doc.

Comment: I have managed to do it using the internal storage. Thank you, Thomas!

Comment: Glad if I was able to help